# Why multimeter 10A fuse blew when measuring voltage?

Tags: multimeter, fuses

Trying to figure out what happened to not make the same mistake. I was measuring if electricity is on or off on wires and with usual V port (600 mA) it showed weirdly huge number - above 1000, where is should have been 220 V. Being amateur at multimeters I tried the 10 A red port and instantly blew the fuse and it seems also fried the multimeter.
Why did it happen?

Comment: *Why did it happen?* Because you never really learnt (or were not taught) about the precautions when using a multimeter.

Comment: what setting was the selection dial set to?

Comment: You have to put your multimeter in voltmeter mode, not ammeter. You are actually wiring a short circuit.

Comment: You may have had one of the probes connected to the wrong jack or accidentally used a setting other than volts.

Comment: voltage... by setting it to AMP you put a short across the supply and thus > 10A will flow so guess what will happen

Comment: Please first learn to use a multimeter properly before connecting it to 220 V. Use a 1.5 V battery to learn in a safe way.

Comment: To measure mains voltage, you have to put the voltmeter in the ACV (may show as ~V) setting of higher than your mains voltage. Usually 600VAC or ~V600.
As Simon said, voltage is about potential energy. A charge (except, in AC, the voltage changes at 50Hz/60Hz). The current is flow. To measure flow, you have to get in the flow. So, if you had a light bulb, you'd put the meter (in ~A mode) between the bulb and the power. To measure voltage, you put it across the bulb. What you did was to put in A mode but across. The current flowed thru a short circuit instead of a bulb. The fuse saved meter!

Comment: Without the fuse, you'd have either tripped a fuse of the house or caused some melted wires and possibly, a fire. There's risk with mains voltages or with large batteries. Such risk can be reduced by reading about stuff. At the moment, you have just a blown fuse. Someone put the fuse in the meter and reduced risk for the rest of us !

Answer (score 9):

The 10A red socket has a low ohm shunt resistor permanently connected to the common black socket. It is inteded only for current measurement. Using that socket it is not possible to measure voltage, as it does not matter what measurement mode is selected on the multimeter.

Basically you short circuited mains Live and Neutral via the shunt resistor of the 10A plug, and thus current larger than 10A passed through the shunt and fuse, and the fuse blew.

Answer (score 4):

Right, while you have a few comments chewing you out for being "dumb", I've done the exact same thing, and that was *after* going to university to learn about this stuff, and after years of experience. So I join you in the "dumb" room, and I raise a glass to you. Just don't do it again.

Here's what you need to know about voltmeters and ammeters, to understand what happened.

An ammeter is designed to measure the flow of current, which means you have to place it actually *in the path of that flow*, but it must be designed to *not interfere with the flow* in any significant way. In other words, an ammeter is deliberately designed to have almost no electrical resistance between its two terminals, so as to appear is if it's not even there.

Referring to the good old water analogy, if you want to know how many litres of water are passing some point in a system each second (analogous to electric current), you actually need a measuring device to be *in the path of flow* itself, so that water actually flows through it, and it can count the litres as they pass. Such a device must offer absolutely no resistance to the flow of water, otherwise it would alter the flow, defeating the point of measuring it in the first place.

By contrast, an ideal voltmeter needs to do the exact opposite, *pass no current*. Again with the water analogy, volts (potential) is represented by water pressure, and to measure that we don't actually need anything flowing through the measurement equipment, all we need is a diaphragm exposed to the molecules of water pressing against it, and that's all.

Strictly speaking, a voltmeter still needs to pass a tiny tiny amount of current, to do its job, but the analogy is relatively water-tight (pun intended). In electrics there's no such thing as "absolute pressure" at some point in a circuit, like there can be with fluids (there's no electrical equivalent of the "vacuum"). Rather, we are interested to know the pressure difference between two points, but in measuring that pressure difference we do not want to introduce a flow of water outside of its normal path, that could interfere with the existing flow in any way. So by this analogy it makes sense that the electrical resistance between the two terminals of a voltmeter should be as close to infinite as possible.

If your multimeter uses the same two terminals to measure both current and voltage, there is potential (another pun, I'm so good at this) for disaster. Imagine that you intend to measure the voltage between the mains live and neutral, but you accidentally forget to turn the multimeter mode selector from, "amps" to "volts". Based on what I just explained, you now understand that the multimeter (now an ammeter) is effectively a direct short circuit between its red and black terminals, and when you apply those terminals between live and neutral, it will be as if you just stuck two prongs of a pair of scissors in there. That's why the fuse blew. If you had switched the multimeter to volts mode, the electrical resistance between the terminals would be extremely high, and the meter would be just fine with almost no current flowing through it.

All good multimeters have separate terminals for current measurement and voltage measurement, because we Humans make exactly these kind of mistakes. I have done this, as you now have, and this was in spite of knowing beforehand everything I have just explained to you. To those that would mock and admonish me I claim to have experience that they do not. And one less multimeter.

Answer (score 3):

It happened because you don’t know to properly use a multimeter. You need to be sure that your multimeter is set to measure voltage and that your probes are in the proper sockets. Thankfully you survived this. Perhaps you should stick with a basic “voltage only” tester in the future if you want to determine if a mains line is live.